# How to add click listener in twitter button?

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, dependencies

I have added a dependency in the `build.gradle` below is my gradle file.

```
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
// (Optional) Monetize using mopub
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.1.1'
// (Optional) Monetize using mopub
```

2.This is my code of main activity code I have initialized the twitter in `onCreate`.and I have added the set on call back click listener I don't know what shall I add to request login.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Twitter.initialize(this);

    TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
            .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
            .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET"))
            .debug(true)
            .build();


    Twitter.initialize(config);

    //calling function login
    login();
}


public void login(){

    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);


    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Eror",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
        }
    });




}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is true but I think it’s better to init button on OnCreate() and because in some case you will have java null pointer error.